# Why is the same utf-8 string fine in print and failing in logging?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

Is there something I need to do by hand for logging that print does for me under the covers in order to log utf-8 strings?

```
for line in unicodecsv.reader(cfile, encoding="utf-8"):
    for i in line:
        print "process_clusters: From CSV: %s" % i
        print "repr: %s" % repr(i)
        log.debug("process_clusters: From CSV: %s", i)
```

My print statement works fine whether the string is Latin-based or Russian Cyrillic.

```
process_clusters: From CSV: escuchan
repr: u'escuchan'
process_clusters: From CSV: говоритъ
repr: u'\u0433\u043e\u0432\u043e\u0440\u0438\u0442\u044a'
```

However, log.debug will not let me pass in the same variable.  I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 765, in emit
    self.stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/codecs.py", line 686, in write
    return self.writer.write(data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/codecs.py", line 351, in write
    data, consumed = self.encode(object, self.errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 28: ordinal not in range(128)
```

My log, formatter and handler is:

```
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
loglvl = getattr(logging, loglevel.upper()) # convert text log level to numeric
log.setLevel(loglvl) # set log level
handler = logging.FileHandler('inflection_finder.log', 'w', 'utf-8')
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('[%(levelname)s] %(message)s'))
log.addHandler(handler)
```

I'm using Python 2.6.7.

Comment: You should show also the creation of the `log` object and any handler added to it. Likely, there the problem lies.

Comment: I think this problem might be Python2.6.x specific. I have not managed to reproduce the problem [in Python2.7](http://ideone.com/UaOH1h).

Comment: @unutbu: I cannot reproduce it on 2.6 either.

Comment: added handler info and repr of strings for some better visibility.

Comment: @unutbu, I was hopeful that you were right.  I installed 2.7, but can still reproduce the problem consistently.

Comment: @kiminoa: It would be very helpful if we had a runnable example that reproduces the problem. Could you try running [this](http://ideone.com/7e3ckz)? It works for me under Python2.6.7 and Python2.7.2. If it works for you too, you could try to modify it incrementally to be more like your real program. At each stage re-run the program until it breaks. That will give us a clue about what is wrong.

Comment: @unutbu, thank you for the effort.  This code also doesn't run for me; same traceback as above.  Right now, I can only get a log by stripping the `u`: `i = '\u0433\u043e\u0432\u043e\u0440\u0438\u0442\u044a'`.  Python would just see that as an ASCII string, though, right?

Comment: @unutbu, can you confirm that you're using `logging==0.4.9.6`?

Comment: @kiminoa: On Python2.6.7 I have `logging.__version__ == 0.5.0.5` and on Python2.7.2 I have `logging.__version__ == 0.5.1.2`.

Comment: @unutbu, `pip install` and `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall` both give me 0.4.9.6.  Where did you get 0.5.0.5?  Maybe this is my problem (wishful thinking).

Comment: I can get `f = codecs.open('/tmp/utf8', 'w', 'utf-8'); f.write(i);
f.close()` to create a file with the same string as `print`, so maybe it is something wrong with my `logging`.

Comment: Converting to a StreamHandler fixes my issue for now.  I'll report back if I get the FileHandler working or figure out what went wrong.

Comment: With your listed log formatter and handler, `log.debug(u'马克')` works and `log.debug('马克')` fails with `UnicodeDecodeError`, so check carefully the type passed to your logging statements.

Comment: @kiminoa: I'm using Ubuntu 11.10. The versions of Python (and logging) come from the standard repository. I'm surprised that all Python2.6.7s do not come with the same version of the `logging` module.

Answer (score 2):

Reading through the traceback, it appears that the log module is attempting to encode the message before it writes it. The message is presumed to be an ASCII string, which it can't be because it contains UTF-8 characters. If you convert your message to Unicode before passing it to the logger it might work.

```
    log.debug(u"process_clusters: From CSV: %s", i)
```

Edit, I noticed your parameter string was already decoded to Unicode so I updated the example accordingly.

Also based on your latest edit, you probably want to use a Unicode string in your setup:

```
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(u'[%(levelname)s] %(message)s'))
                                     --^--
```

Comment: I'd found this suggestion elsewhere, but get the exact same traceback with this change.  :-/

Comment: If the `repr` of the variable already has `u'\u0433\u043e\u0432\u043e\u0440\u0438\u0442\u044a'`, would that imply that it's already Unicode, already utf-8 encoded, or am I being naïve?

Comment: rats. I was so hoping that Formatter edit would fix it, but I'm still getting the traceback with both of the changes suggested.  Are you on 2.6, by any chance?

Comment: @kiminoa, I'm on 2.7 but I must admit I'm not using the `log` module. I just know that if you're using Unicode consistently throughout then encoding to UTF-8 is guaranteed to work without errors. Your `repr` indicates the string is Unicode, not UTF-8 - there's a difference.

Comment: Is there a different log module you prefer?  I'm super new to Python, and keen to learn more about what works better for everyone.  I was replacing my home-brewed if debug == 1: print "faux log" with a proper module under the theory that the `log` module would work better, but I'm on hour 5 in this rabbit hole and starting to make small growling noises. also, and please forgive the newbie meta, I can't figure out how to @ your name ... others' names work but @ with mark-ransom just comes up blank.  Is that a setting specific to you?

Comment: @kiminoa, my Python work to date has been small utilities and hobby projects so I've been able to make do with print statements. I've just given myself a crash course on `logging` to see if I could help further, but I'm not able to reproduce your symptoms either. There must be a detail you're leaving out. As to why `@` doesn't work for you, I don't know - it always auto-fills the name for me, all I have to do is type the first letter or two and hit Tab.

Answer (score 1):

All the string vs. unicode in Python2 is a mess... fortunately corrected in Python3. But assuming that moving to Python3 is not an option, here it goes.

As I see it, there are two options when using `logging` with respect to encodings:

1. Open the file as binary and use all the strings as byte-strings.
2. Open the file as text and use all the strings as unicode-strings.

Any other option is doomed!

The problem is that you specify encoding `"utf-8"` when opening the File but your russian text is a unicode string.

So you can do one (just one) of the following:

1. Open the file in binary, that is, remove the `"utf-8"` argument from the `FileStream` construction.
2. Convert all the relevant texts to unicode-strings, that includes the arguments to `log.debug` and the one to `logging.Formatter`.